# Update many objects in one query DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to bulk update ("is_read" = True) Message instanses by given list of ids in one request with this code:

```
{"ids": [11, 4, 7]}
```

Model:

```
class Message(models.Model):

text = models.TextField(max_length=500, verbose_name=_("Text"))
sender = models.ForeignKey(
    to=User,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name="sender_message",
    verbose_name=_("User"),
)
thread = models.ForeignKey(
    to="Thread",
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name="thread_message",
    verbose_name=_("Thread"),
)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=_("Created"))
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name=_("Updated"))
is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_("Is read"))
```

I have this serializer:

```
class MessageIsReadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:

        model = Message
        fields = ("id", "text", "sender", "is_read")
```

And method in views.py:

```
class MessageIsRead(APIView):

permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
queryset = Message.objects.all()

def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    id_list = request.data['ids']
    instances = []
    for item in id_list:
        obj = self.queryset.filter(id=item)
        obj.is_read = True
        instances.append(obj)
    serializer = MessageIsReadSerializer(instances, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("messages-read/", MessageIsRead.as_view()),
]
```

But as a result of running this query I get an error:

```
AttributeError at /messages-read/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `text` on serializer 
`MessageIsReadSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the 
`QuerySet` instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'text'.
```

What is wrong?

With help of [Bartosz Stasiak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17185927/bartosz-stasiak) I've fixed my verion of put method.

```
    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    id_list = request.data['ids']
    instances = []
    for item in id_list:
        obj = self.queryset.get(id=item)
        obj.is_read = True
        obj.save()
        instances.append(obj)
    serializer = MessageIsReadSerializer(instances, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: here you are getting a queryset, not an instance, so later in your code you are appending querysets to the `instances` list. If you want to access single instance you should use `get` instead of `filter`

```
single_instance = self.queryset.get(id=item)
```

If you want to update multiple items you can use:

```
def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    id_list = request.data['ids']

    instances = self.queryset.filter(id__in=id_list)
    instances.update(is_read=True)
    
    serializer = MessageIsReadSerializer(instances, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Thanks for a solution. It needs to be improved, I get an error ('int' object is not iterable).

Comment: Which line throw this error?

Comment: Exception Location: E:\Pyton-projects\yalantis_django\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py, line 686, in to_representation

Comment: I realized where was an error.`update()` returns numbers of rows updated. I updated my answer taking that into account. Sorry again. If serializer still doesn't show updated values then probably you need to refresh query